# Tratar Response cURL com PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou integrando um serviço de email com *cURL* e *PHP* e gostaria de pegar a resposta que vem nesse formato:

```
{
  "id": 8
}
```

Como faço para pegar o numero do campo `ID` com PHP?

Comment: Dá um "var_dump()" no valor retornado e verifica se é um objeto ou um array. Se for array, vc vai usar $retorno["id"], se for objeto, você vai usar $retorno->id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não colocou seu código, vou exemplificar bem resumidamente aqui uma possível solução

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$retorno = json_decode($response, true)
echo $response["id"];
```

Comment: Valeu, extamente assim que resolveu!